# Updating Values in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a bot that fetches data from a website through selenium and I want to plot that data on a GUI. Bot sends Email and Notifications as well, I need someway to change value of `real_email` and `real_noti` Live, anytime.

Whole BOT Code is in a `while True:` loop.

Issue that I am having right now is, I was thinking of adding my BOT CODE and pysimplegui in the same `while` loop but the program stops at `event, values = window.read()` for input and will not go further input is passed.

Here is the Demo Code.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkAmber')    # Keep things interesting for your users
elem = sg.Text('Email and Notfication ON', key='-TEXT-')
layout = [[elem],
          [sg.Input(key='-IN-')],
          [sg.Input(key='-IN')],
          [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Exit()]]

window = sg.Window('Window that stays open', layout)
real_email = "On"
real_noti = "On"
while True:                             # The Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    email = values['-IN-']
    notification = values['-IN']

    if email == "On":
        real_email = "On"
    elif email == "Off":
        real_email = "Off"
    if notification == "On":
        real_noti = "On"
    elif  notification =="Off":
        real_noti = "Off"
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break
    print("Testing Print Value After .read()")

window.close()
```

I just want to change these 2 values in this loop. Maybe a way to use Checkbox or Only Buttons?

Comment: [Demo_Button_Toggle.py](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Button_Toggle.py)
You can find many demo programs on GitHub of PySimpleGUI. I think one of these examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `enable_event=True` in the `sg.Input(key='-IN-')` will be `sg.Input(key='-IN-', enable_event=True)`